# pweibull inverse R

Tags: r, inverse, weibull

Let's say `x = 1000`, `shape=2`, `scale=1500`.
Then `y=pweibull(x=1000, shape = 2, scale = 1500)` produces `y=0.3588196`.

I need to find `x`, given `(y, shape, scale)`.

However, none of `pinvweibull`, `qinvweibull`, `levinvweibull`, etc. is giving me `x`.

How can I find the `x` for which I have `y=pweibull(x=1000, shape = 2, scale = 1500)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `qweibull` which is the inverse cdf:

```
qweibull(0.3588196, 2, 1500)
[1] 1000
```

Check the documentation with `?qweibull`. You'll see four functions `d*`, `p*`, `q*`, and `r*` for density, cdf, inverse cdf, and random variates. This is pretty standard for distributions in R (see e.g. `?dnorm` or `?dbeta`).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Words have no meaning in `R`, then!
I had started to do it with MATLAB!

Comment: Words do have meaning if you read the help pages and study a bit of statistics.

Comment: Another question. How/why, for e.g. Ben Bolker, can edit my question?

Comment: It's not personal or anything. The community can edit posts to fix typos or improve clarity so others coming to the question can benefit more from the question. (Those of with less reputation still have to get the edits approved.)

Comment: Dear 42, I have studied math for >12 years. "inverse" of a function have, has, and always will have a crystal clear meaning. I may have had prejudice in considering pinvweibull is inverse of pweibull, like when y=f(x) then x = f^(-1)(y). But for sure, `R` is not making it easy!

Comment: How about `dweibull`?

Comment: @NoLie What's your question exactly? `dweibull` will evaluate the probably density function of the Weibull distribution. For example, `dweibull(5, 2, 3)` returns `0.06908503`, meaning the density at `x=5` of a Weibull with `shape=2` and `scale=3`. Check out the PDF of the [Weibull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). Hope that helps. (Note that density is different than probability).

Comment: question is like the initial question. Let's say you have `0.06908503` and `scale=2` and `shape=3`, you want to figure out the two `x`s for which `dweibull(x, 2, 3) == 0.06908503`

Comment: Ah, that's going to be more difficult and I'm not aware of any built-in solutions in R. I think you might need to invert the pdf yourself. A brute force method would be to just try a bunch of `x` values until you get something close to the density estimate you want. You might want to ask a new question entirely.